# ¿Cómo puedo escribir en un archivo Python desde otro?

Tags: python, table, qt-designer

Hola quiero escribir las variables (*introduce_producto*, *introduce_precio*, *introduce_marca*) en otro archivo Python, quiero hacer un tipo de tabla de productos.  Gracias por adelantado.

Aquí el código:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets

qtCreatorFile = "preset-añadir_productos.ui" # Nombre del archivo aquí.
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_agree.clicked.connect(self.boton_agree)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(301, 370)

    def boton_agree(self):
        introduce_producto = self.Inp_nombre_de_producto.text()
        introduce_precio = self.Inp_nombre_de_precio.text() 
        introduce_marca = self.Inp_nombre_de_marca.text()
        
        print(introduce_producto)
        print(introduce_marca)
        print(introduce_precio)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app =  QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Puedes escribir cualquier cosa en cualquier archivo (si tienes permiso), pero ¿qué pretendes lograr? ¿Cual es resultado que buscar?

Comment: en esa ventana el usuario tine que poner el nomre del producto, el objetivo es que lo que el usuario dijite aparezca en una tabla que esta en otro archivo python. Es mas o menos como una lista de contactos para que me entiendas mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digamos que tenemos un archivo `data.py` que contiene el saldo acumulado de algún proceso

**archivo data.py**

```
saldo = 10
```

En el archivo `main.py` queremos leer y actualizar ese dato:

**archivo main.py**

```
import data

print(data.saldo)
data.saldo += 1
with open("data.py", "w") as archivo:
    archivo.write(f"saldo={data.saldo}")
```

Cada vez que ejecutas

```
python3 main
```

`saldo` se incrementa en uno.

Es como grabar y leer cualquier archivo.

Nota: Si lo ejecutas desde dentro del IDE, asegurate que el directorio de trabajo coincida con el directorio donde están los fuentes.

Comment: Pero si las variables estan dentro de una funcion como en este caso que hago?

Comment: En realidad, la manera recomendable es usar el modulo `configparser` de Python3, con lo que puedes manejar un archivo tipo `.ini` (como en Windows). Plantea una nueva pregunta `"¿Cómo guardar valores de configuración de esta función?"` para darte una respuesta completa. Publica el código de la función para que la pregunta se ajuste a las reglas del sitio.